# Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-object in Observer.php while payment using payUmoney

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am using `Magento 1.9.2.4` version. I am using `SMS module` for receiving SMS after placing the order .While selecting option as "Pay Using Credit Card / Debit Card / Net Banking" it is redirecting to `payUmoney` money page and amount deducting but order placing time error getting like this

```
   Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-object in  model/Observer.php on line 125
```

My observer code:

```
        public function salesOrderPlace(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
          {
       try{
        Mage::log("New Order Placed");


        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 

        $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
        Mage::log("Order ID:".$incrementId);

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

        if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order)
        { 
          if($this->getHelper()->issalesOrderPlace())
          { 

            $mobilenumbers = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();

            $message = $this->getHelper()->getOrderMessage($order); //enter Your Message
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
            $retunValue = $this->getHelper()->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"New Order");   

          }
          if($this->getHelper()->issalesOrderPlaceForAdmin())
          { 
            $mobilenumbers = $this->getHelper()->getAdminMobileNumber();         
            $message = $this->getHelper()->getOrderMessageForAdmin($order); //enter Your Message
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            //curlApicall : this method will return tru or fale.
            $retunValue = $this->getHelper()->curlApiCall($message,$mobilenumbers,$customerName,"New Order");   

          } 
        }

    //return false;
  }catch(Exception $e) {
         Mage::log($e->getMessage());
  } 
}
```